# Query which returns a table of results based on search parameters in an array?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgres. How can I write a query which returns a table of results based on search parameters in an array?

Eg if I have a table like this:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | James |
| 2 | Sarah |
| 3 | Bob |

I'd want to pass `[1,3]` to a query and have it return:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | James |
| 3 | Bob |

Comment: `where id = any(array[1,3])`

Answer (score 0):

`select * from MyTable where id = any(array[1,3])`

Comment: Besides SQL code itself, the context of why this answer is the right one for the question, should be brought, as well.